# Null pointer exception upon adding an object to a list

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a class 'AdResources'. I created a list to hold AdResources objects

```
private List<AdResources> adResourcesList = null;
```

Then I created an AdResources object `AdResources map = new AdResources();`
I also added some data to `map` by `map.setType(((JSONArray)nearbyPlacesData.get(i)).optString(0));` (Nothing is null here, cross checked)

After all this I do `adResourcesList.add(map);`. I get null pointer exception here. This is weird because running a debugger, just before executing adResourcesList.add(map) I can see that the `map` object is not null, hence why the NPE?

Also to be noted is, I am running this from an AsyncTask doInBackground.

Comment: I wonder why the down vote? Yes it is an easy catch but isnt SO for all types of question? easy or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to initialize the list itself before adding.

```
private List<AdResources> adResourcesList = new ArrayList<AdResources>();
```

You clearly show that the list is `null` prior to adding it, so obviously it will throw a `NullPointerException` when you try to add something.

Comment: Wow, I cant believe I made that rookie mistake. Thanks for pointing it out ! I will accept your answer as soon as 10 min is over